# How to add different effects on image captured by camera

Tags: android

i am making an application on selfie camera .and i m new on photography application.i have not got any idea that how to apply different **effects like blur,saturation,brightness,etc on captured image** .i search a lot,using many libraries,git hub code etc.But cannot find my solution,anyone who help me sort out this problem.

Comment: you can use any third party library for this check this link
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/47

Comment: i already apply all these libraries ,but the question is how to implement this on application .

Comment: thanks for your response ,sorry for late reply

Comment: how can i download the  FotorSDK-xxx.zip any luink peaswe

Comment: if you see this link http://developers.fotor.com/  they are saying sdk creation is in development ... sooner it will be available

Comment: try this one too https://developers.aviary.com/   if you want !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself then you have to play with Bitmap and create your own filters which you would like to apply. Also there are multiple free photo editing sdk's which can help you do it much easier.

You can check below links -

- Aviary photo editing sdk - https://developers.aviary.com/
- Fotor photo editing sdk - http://developers.fotor.com/

Comment: sorry this link cannot helpfull for me

Comment: can you tell me how tto apply effects on custom camera plaese

Comment: I added the links in the above posting. Documentation is already provided for both the sdks.

Comment: but these links not helpful for me